# XCompose is not updated for Urxvt when window manager starts

Tags: terminal, x11, awesome, rxvt, compose-key

I am using [awesome WM](https://awesomewm.org/). When I start my window manager, I run `setxkbmap -option compose:menu` which has a `~/.XCompose` with various extra definitions. Those work fine in Gvim, Firefox, Signal, and Slack (for example) but not in urxvt or anything under urxvt.

I tried using the above command as part of `~/.xprofile`, as a `run_once(…)` command in awesome configuration, restarting all terminal, and nothing changes: the binding are not present in the terminal.

*What am I missing here?*

PS: Just in case, yes, the terminal has all the correct glyphs…

PS 2: I do not believe this is awesome specific but added in case it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `urxvt` does not respect `~/.XCompose`, (See: [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt)).

> Many distribution do also load settings from the ~/.Xresources file when X starts. urxvt will consult the following files/resources in order, with later settings overwriting earlier ones:
>
> 1. app-defaults file in $XAPPLRESDIR
> 2. $HOME/.Xdefaults
> 3. RESOURCE_MANAGER property on root-window of screen 0
> 4. SCREEN_RESOURCES property on root-window of the current screen
> 5. $XENVIRONMENT file OR $HOME/.Xdefaults-
> 6. resources specified via -xrm on the commandline

Also, `urxvt` has its own key bindings, (Also found in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt)), which may interfere with what you are trying to do.

> Unfortunately, this will override built-in key mappings.